# Current 'in' something

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

Not the smartest question but when you have a series circuit and it says that the current in R is something, isnt the current the same throughout the circuit? Or if you look at only the things that are happening to the electrons from one end of the resistor to the other its slightly different? and when we talk about current in general its just the average ?

You can have current as ?$$I_{total}=R_{total}*V_{total}$$ but in a series circuit is there any situation in which you wouldn't look for $I_{total}$?

Comment: Current can split and merge at circuit junctions. Kirchoff's Current Law tells us that the sum of all of the currents flowing in to any junction must equal the sum of currents leaving it in the same instant. Of course, in a simple loop circuit, every junction has just one wire coming in, and one wire leaving, so in that special case, the current must be the same everywhere in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that in a series circuit, the current is the same throughout the circuit.  For a series circuit, talking about the current "in a resistor" is unnecessarily specific.

However, when you start working with parallel circuits, there are different currents in different parts of the circuit.  We have found that, in English, the phrasing of "current in R" is a very effective way of specifying which current we are talking about.  So it's a good notation to get used to for working through other problems later.

It's also very useful when we start talking about power.  The phrasing of "current in R" makes it very clear that that particular current is the correct one to use in the power equation $P=I^2R$.  This may not be too important in the introductory phases, but when building practical circuits it is very important to make sure one selects a resistor that is rated for the correct power dissipation.  Otherwise one suddenly finds that their circuit is full of "light emitting resistors," which also let the magic smoke out of the circuit. (Despite what your teacher says, all electronics actually operate on 'magic smoke.'  The proof of this fact is that when you let the magic smoke out of the components, the circuit stops working)

So yes, it's a bit superfluous to speak to "the current in R" in a simple series circuit, but in future circuits that particular notation will serve you well.

Comment: thank you, actually the question that confused me was asking about the power dissipated given that the current in R was x.